# Скрытие контейнера с определённым текстом

Tags: javascript

Есть страница с более 100 однотипных контейнеров типа текст текст данные, нужно скрыть его, если в нём есть слово test с учётом регистра.

А также кнопка, по которой происходит это действие, а при повторном клике происходит возврат к исходному положению.

Это не нагло мне просить у вас подобное? Не знаю у кого такое спросить даже.
Извините.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться jQuery, а именно:

- Селектором [`contains`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) для нахождения элементов которые нужно скрыть.
- Методом [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) для изменения видимости элемента (если элемент виден, то скрывает его, если скрыт, то показывает).

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(`.item:contains('77')`).toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Будем скрывать элементы, содержащие «77»</h3>
<ul id="container">
  <li class="item">простой блок, содержит 77</li>
  <li class="item">простой блок, не содержит</li>
  <li class="item">сложный блок, <span>содержит 77</span></li>
  <li class="item">сложный блок, <span>не содержит</span></li>
</ul>
<button>Кнопка</button>
```